# How to implement a plist with Vision in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, plist

I am trying to create a program that uses Vision to recognize canned drinks and display the name and caffeine content into two UILabels on the screen. I trained a model in CreateML to recognize Monster and Del's Shandy. I have a small plist (for testing purposes) and some code that I thought would display the drink, but it doesn't seem to be working. I have gotten the name and confidence level to display, although this is not exactly what I want. Here's the code that I have been using to try to access the plist:

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                    if self.productID != nil {
                        guard self.productCatalog[self.productID] != nil else {
                            return
                        }
                        self.outputLabel.text = self.productCatalog[self.productID]?["Name"] as? String
                        self.caffeineContentLabel.text = self.productCatalog[self.productID]?["Caffeine"] as? String

                        
                    }
```

The method I used to read the dictionary of the plist is as follows:

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ProductCatalog", ofType: "plist") {
            productCatalog = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: [String: Any]]
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can add more info for anyone that may need. Been watching YouTube for hours.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do or how it differs from the code that you have. You say "I have gotten the name and confidence level to display, although this is not exactly what I want." -- how so? Is there a value in the `plist` that isn't displayed? Are you sure you're accessing it correctly? You haven't shown the `plist` at all, so it's hard to say what's in there or how to access it.

Comment: Have you checked to see that `productCatalog` isn't `nil` (ie that you are reading the plist successfully?). I would also suggest you ditch the plist and store a JSON file in your bundle.  Then you can use `Codable` to get a dictionary of structs with your data instead of raw dictionaries of any.

Comment: "I have gotten the name and confidence level to display, although this is not exactly what I want"  What is your question?  What exactly is it that you want, then?

Comment: Google PropertyListDecoder and PropertyListEncoder